# What is the current situation at Bokor Hill Station, Cambodia?

Tags: planning, cambodia

Ok, I know this comes up every now and then, but the situation at [Bokor Hill Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokor_Hill_Station) is constantly changing. I understand the area and road is now open, but I'm concerned about the development. The thing that appeals to me is the abandoned nature of the area, but I'm worried this has gone now. I don't mind if the new road has brought more tourists, but how much progress has there been on this Las Vegas resort? Are there the foundations of one or two buildings near by, or is the whole area a building site? I've seen pictures of the old buildings covered in scaffolding, and I've heard you can't go in because they're used for worker housing - is this still the case?

If I can see the old building and wander round them with the new works out of view, so I can get and idea of what it was like a few years ago, I'll probably still go, but if not I might give it a miss.

Any updates, (even better pictures) on this?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a close-vote on this.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I don't understand either? The only thing I can think of is that this question is specific to this point in time and will become obsolete in the future. This is a common reason for closures on other SE sites, but this is going to be a reality when it comes to travel - situations a rte constantly changing due to politics/development/nature etc. I am a great believer in this site, but closing questions withou a good reason is going to kill it, as it has seriously damaged other SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, it sounds like a lot of the new development is happening, and the ruins aren't much to see any more.

This [blog post about going there](http://whatsdavedoing.com/amidst-ruins-bokor-hill-station/) rates the scooter trip there and back as the highlight, and as he cynically puts it:

> Because if there is one thing Cambodia needs more of in its national
>   parks, it is apparently golf courses, entertainment complexes and five
>   star hotels with a design that requires suppression of the gag reflex.

The resort and hotel is up and running, with [a website with all the details](http://www.thansurbokor.com/) for bookings and the like.

Another [blog has a piece written just **yesterday** about it](http://sconzani.blogspot.ca/2013/01/the-ghosts-of-bokor-hill.html), which seems to be as recent as you're likely to get.  They too point out the casino being a blot on the landscape, and include a picture:

[image]
(from [sconzani.blogspot.ca](http://sconzani.blogspot.ca/2013/01/the-ghosts-of-bokor-hill.html))

They point out that it's only going to get worse in years to come:

> The first stages of the new development have now been completed, with
>   a sprawling and exceedingly ugly casino already open for business.
>   Sokimex have huge plans for their hill – as well as the casino, they
>   plan on constructing more hotels, golf courses, and water parks, as
>   well as a major port complex on the nearby coast, from where they
>   intend helicoptering guests from visiting cruise ships to the plateau
>   resort. It all sounds as hideous as their new casino.

Comment: and again well researched